# How to use more than one ChangeNotifierProvider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I recently started using `provider` for my state management and I know how to use one at a time.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ChangeNotifierProvider<Reader>(
        create: (context) => new Reader(),
        child: _HomeBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But now I have two different classes and I want to add both of them and be able to access in my widget tree.

How can I add more than one `ChangeNotifierProvider` in `Flutter`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option (not recommended) is to nest 2 Providers:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider<Reader>(
  create: (_) => Reader(),
  child: ChangeNotifierProvider<SomethingElse>(
    create: (_) => SomethingElse(),
    child: ChangeNotifierProvider<AnotherThing>(
      create: (_) => AnotherThing(),
      child: someWidget,
    ),
  ),
),
```

This is not recommended because, as the documentation states:

> When injecting many values in big applications, Provider can rapidly become pretty nested:

But, another suggestion from the [Provider package itself](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) is to use the [MultiProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/MultiProvider-class.html):

```dart
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<Reader>(create: (_) => Reader()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<SomethingElse>(create: (_) => SomethingElse()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<AnotherThing>(create: (_) => AnotherThing()),
  ],
  child: _HomeBody(),
)
```

Both approaches work the same but the second one is more readable. As the documentation words:

> The behavior of both examples is strictly the same. MultiProvider only changes the appearance of the code.

Example adapted from the [provider flutter package page](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and adapted to your case.

Comment: thanks for answer! I want to know why did your write `ChangeNotifierProvider` in first provider, then just `Provider` for the second one. I named both of my providers as `ChangeNotifierProvider`, is it something wrong? should I do as you have did?

Comment: No. It was just an example because I didnt know what are the other providers you have.  A ChangeNotifierProvider is as valid as a Provider. Provider itself is just a more general use case. They are all valid providers. I can change the example for you.

Comment: no just asked if I am missing something there. appreciated

Comment: Probably, you can alter the answers. The recommended one you could show first and then another alternative. This will help people to find the answer quickly

Answer (score 2):

You could use MultiProvider

This guide helped me, hope it will help you too...

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>(builder: (context) => Counter(0)),
    ProxyProvider<Counter, ThemeSwitch>.custom(
      builder: (context, counter, previous) {
        final theme = previous ?? ThemeSwitch(ThemeState.light);
        theme.themeState =
              (counter.value > 5) ? ThemeState.dark : ThemeState.light;
        return theme;
      },
      dispose: (context, value) => value.dispose(),
      providerBuilder: (_, value, child) =>
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(notifier: value, child: child),
    ),
  ],
)
```