# How to use Provider with Base Class in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have base and derived classes like this:

```
abstract class A extends ChangeNotifier{....}
class B extends A{....}
```

I am using provider like this:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<B>(create: (context) => B())
```

and accessing using both A and B(depending on situation) like this:

```
Provider.of<A>(context) //This does not work. Why?
Provider.of<B>(context) //This works.
```

How do I correctly use base class with `Provider.of` i.e. `Provider.of<A>(context)`?

Edit: The ChangeNotifierProvider is only for B. I do not have a provider for A. But, I want to access using A as A is the base class of B.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61123003/how-to-use-more-than-one-changenotifierprovider-in-flutter

Comment: @RaphaelKoh The linked question is for using multiple 'different' ChangeNotifiers. This question is for using one ChangeNotifier but accessing it using both it and its base class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to do something like this:

```dart
final b = B();
ChangeNotifierProvider<A>.value(value: b)
ChangeNotifierProvider<B>.value(value: b)
```

Then you can access your `B` class by using either:

```dart
Provider.of<A>(context) //This now works.
Provider.of<B>(context) //This works.
```