# How can I use different child classes as providers in flutter?

Tags: flutter, inheritance, flutter-provider

I have the interface of an API using an abstract class and multiple implementations aka child classes.

```dart
abstract class API extends ChangeNotifier {
    void foo();
}

class TestAPI extends API {
  @override
  void foo() {
    // do something
  }


class RealAPI extends API {
  @override
  void foo() {
    // do something else
  }
```

Now I want to be able to switch those different implementations as providers without redeclaring all my dependent widgets. So they use the parent class:

```
Provider.of<API>(context)
```

I tried using this

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => TestAPI(),// RealAPI()
    child: // ...
```

but then flutter can't find my provider

`Could not find the correct Provider<API> above this Widget`

Comment: I think you need to use the implementation class, maybe using MyWidget<T extends API> and Provider.of<T>(context).
But I'm not sure to understand your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify the type of provider flutter should look for. So pass in the parent class there:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider<API>( // notice the type here
    create: (context) => TestAPI(),
    child: // ...
)
```

Comment: the answer to this question demonstrates a more complex case
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64487800/how-to-use-provider-with-base-class-in-flutter-dart